# How to avoid tag injection in Elasticsearch highlighting responses?

Tags: elasticsearch, escaping

When I query ElasticSearch and request highlights, the highlights field in the response uses `<em></em>` tags to delineate the highlighted portion. But if the document itself contains the strings `<em>` or `</em>` then I don't see how to tell from the response whether a given tag is highlight metadata or part of the original document.

Of course it's possible to set custom pre_tags and post_tags, but whatever I set them to, those values might still appear inside the document.

Is there a solution to this other than escaping html characters saved in ElasticSearch documents?

Comment: As you mentioned, you can use the custom pre_tags and post_tags with value which not common in html tags like <eshighlight> </eshighlight>. As per my understanding this is the only way to resolved this issue.